# I am constantly getting this error in android studio while building an app how to fix it?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3NI4.png)[Error shown on the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOXyi.png)

I retried it multiple times but the emulator is not able to run the app.
The terminal shows the error has been caused due to insufficient space
How to fix the storage issue shown so that the emulator is able to run it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Android Studio, select Device Manager(top right of your Android Studio) and a dialog window like this will appear.

[image: Device Manager selected on Android Studio]

2. Click on the three dots on the far end and a menu will show.

[image: Device Manager menu showing]

3. Now click on `Wipe Data` and you will see `Size on Disk` reduce significantly.

[image: Wiped data from Android emulator.]

**PS: This is like a factory reset on a physical device. All your aps on the emulator will be deleted.**